# Method on BackgroundWorker is freezing GUI

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, backgroundworker, freeze

I'm trying to run a method that gets file list from specified folders and represents it in DataGridView. The method is ran in BackgroundWorker, so I'm expecting GUI to stay active. But it still freezes. Here's an example:

```
private void startScan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bckgrFileScanner.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void bckgrFileScanner_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
//for each folder in list perform this function, which scans folder and gets all files
    for (int i = 0; i < folderList.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        GetFileList(ref scannedFiles, folderList.Items[i].ToString(), bckgrFileScanner);

    }
 }

public static void GetFileList(ref List<FileInfo> fList, string fPath, BackgroundWorker scanner)      
{
     DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(fPath);
     FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles();

     foreach (FileInfo fiTemp in fi)
     {                
          if (fiTemp.Name.StartsWith("~$") == false)
          {
              //adds items to list of all scanned files
              fList.Add(fiTemp);
              //reports file name to ProgressChanged method
              scanner.ReportProgress(0, fiTemp);
          }
     }
     DirectoryInfo[] dFolders = di.GetDirectories();

     //use recursion for all subfolders
     foreach (DirectoryInfo d in dFolders)
     {
          GetFileList(ref fList, d.FullName, scanner);
     }
}

private void bckgrFileScanner_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //userstate is filename, so add it to table
    filesDataGrid.Rows.Add(e.UserState.ToString());  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not update your reportprogress event at each row of your loop. 
Instead, call the ReportProgress every 2 or more iteration (the best way is to compute et step to not update at each row if you have 200000)
And fill the grid when the whole process has finished (in the completed event), to update all the rows. I think progress is meant to update a progress only, not fill a bunch of data into a control but i may be wrong :
from [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker) :

> Tips You probably know more than you think about the BackgroundWorker
>   class. BackgroundWorker has a name that might indicate it is more
>   complex than it really is. There are many more details about threading
>   and abort calls, but once you understand that BackgroundWorker is just
>   a structural "overlay" to threads in Windows Forms, it is quite
>   intuitive. Here are the steps again:
>
> First, call RunWorkerAsync with an argument. You can pass any argument
>   to this method on BackgroundWorker, including null. It simply must
>   inherit from object, which everything does.
>
> Second, custom processing is run. Your expensive code is executed in
>   the DoWork method. Insert pause here as your program does its
>   calculations.
>
> Third, it finishes. When your processing is done, RunWorkerCompleted
>   is called. In this method, you receive the result. In this way, your
>   BackgroundWorker object modifies an object on another thread, and you
>   receive it when it is done.

I think it hangs up when too much updates in a short time are required, and even calling Apllication.DoEvents() does not work all the times.
I hope it will help, a little late i know, but it's better than never ;)

Comment: I fixed it already in a different way (smaller table with paging function), bet thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This (simplified) example works for me and has a lovely responsive UI:

```
    BackgroundWorker m_objWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

    public FormBackgroundWorkerExample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_objWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        m_objWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(m_objWorker_DoWork);
        m_objWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(m_objWorker_ProgressChanged);
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_objWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void m_objWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //for each folder in list perform this function, which scans folder and gets all files
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            m_objWorker.ReportProgress(i, "FooBar");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private void m_objWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(e.UserState.ToString()); 
    }
```

Perhaps this'll give you an idea where yours is going wrong?

Edit: You might want to try it without the datagrid just to try and isolate the problem.

Comment: I was using backgroundworker for other methods earlier the same style I am using it here and it was working just fine. I was thinking maybe it has something to do with recursion, but after removing it from my method it still freezes.

Comment: Without adding rows to datagrid it works fine, no freezing, so problem is there, but I can't figure out why, because I was using similar code before, where table is updated from ProgressChanged and no freezing was noticed there.

Comment: @andree I've updated the example; adding rows to the datagrid presents no problems here. Is there anything else that might be relevant that hasn't been included in your code sample?

Comment: @andree Are you registered to DataGrid events? If the event handlers perform long-running operations this would explain why your app freezes.

Comment: The thing is that ProgressChanged performs adding A LOT OF new rows - one for each file. And what exactly do you mean by "registered to DataGrid" events?

Answer (score 1):

Might be because you are locking the backgroundworker itself.

In your DoWork method

```
GetFileList(ref scannedFiles, folderList.Items[i].ToString(), bckgrFileScanner);
```

Normaly you should have access to bckgrFileScanner from your DoWork Method, and just call it directly as bckgrFileScanner.ReportProgress( .... .... )

When passing it like you do, it will now report progress on the background workers thread, which is now not the same as the UI thread. (who owns bckgrFileScanner)

**Edit** To clarify:

1. Your UI thread owns bckgrFileScanner and fires RunWorkerAsync()
2. The stuff that happens in DoWork is now on its own thread.
3. The DoWork thread is "stealing" the variable bckgrFileScanner
4. Now the ReportProgress fires on the DoWork thread, instead of the UIs thread

Comment: GetFileList(ref scannedFiles, folderList.Items[i].ToString(), bckgrFileScanner);
I already have this line, but when using recursion I'm calling scanner instead, because I don't have access to bckgrFileScanned inside GetFileList method. Sorry, but I don't really understand what I need to change here.

Comment: Is there any reasons to why you want to have that method static?
Make it nonstatic and use bckgrFileScanner directly instead of "scanner.ReportProgress". 

If you're going to use it as a tool from other sources/classes, then you could do something like a "public static class ScanDirectories{ .. }" have the backgroundworker doing it's directory traversing there, and add return the complete list when its done through an event. Or (if you are useing wpf/silverlight) add items to an ObservableCollection<string> and listen to changed events on that.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `ReportProgress` on scanner. Shouldn't be that `bckgrFileScanner`?

**EDIT**

Is by any chance the scannedFiles list databound to the UI? If so a change to the list causes a UI update.

Comment: In method GetFileList "scanner" is reference to bckgrFileScanner, thats why I'm calling scanner insted of bckgrFileScanner. Besides, in this method, I don't even have access to bckgrFileScanner.

Comment: Ah, yes I missed that due to the sideways scrolling. You could use Debug.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread...) to trace what thread is executing the code so you can check whether your UI thread is really locked or something else is broken.

Comment: No, scannedFiles list is used like global variable for whole form.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:

I think you just want to report the filename:

```
//reports file name to ProgressChanged method
scanner.ReportProgress(0, fiTemp.Name);
```

Or the folderList in DoWork is a UI control:

```
for (int i = 0; i < folderList.Items.Count; i++)
{
    GetFileList(ref scannedFiles, folderList.Items[i].ToString(), bckgrFileScanner);
}
```

Why not pass the list of folders to the RunWorkerAsync method.

Comment: Thats true, my mistake. Not the reason for freezing though.

Comment: folderList is ListBox, that contains all folder. Tried passing folderList items as array of strings to RunWorkerAsync - still no luck.